# how to recover deleted ntfs patition with data entirely while installing ubuntu 13.04

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery

I've installed ubuntu 13.04 onto my hp 2231tx computer. During installation all of my data was erased. I didn't know all of my three partitions would be deleted.

I was shocked after finding out that all of my personal data was erased. I didn't know what to do to resolve this problem so I search google for an answer.

I found a program called testdisk and I used it to recover about half of my data. Among this data weren't my personal photos and videos. Is there a way to recover the other half?

Comment: Next time you do anything with your disks please make sure you have a up do date backup ready. In theory all your data should be safe, but things always can go wrong. Also make backups of your data regularly, also in normal use drives will fail.

Comment: while installing new os it is suppose to erase primary partition like windows not like happend with me..

Comment: maybe, I am not sure if I agree. but still even when I do the formatting manually I first back my important files up whatever OS I use. I don't want to chastise you but I hope you at least will learn this lesson from this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, you should use this as a learning experience about the importance of backups, particularly when doing anything risky like repartitioning the disk or installing a new OS.

That said, there's a chance that [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) or a similar tool (there are some Windows-specific tools that are similar in broad strokes, but I don't have any URLs handy) may be able to recover some files. Be aware, though, that the longer you use the disk in its current state, the more likely it is that additional files will be irrecoverably damaged or erased. Thus, if you really need any files from that disk, ***STOP USING IT IMMEDIATELY***! Use it *only* along with PhotoRec (or something similar), and be sure to use *another physical disk* as the recovery target.

Answer (score 1):

In short: **no, your data cannot be recovered**, and please **learn** from this experience and back up your data regularly, and also make sure you **fully understand** what you are doing to your system ***before*** you start. By and large, if you erased your partitions, you've erased your data.

The more you use the drive and write data to it, the less change any retrieval application will be able to recover anything, so in all honesty, if you've formatted the drive, installed Ubuntu and booted into it, the chances of you being able to recover anything are almost nil - I'm surprised the tool you chose was able to recover any data at all.

Comment: The tool he used reads the data directly from the drive and not the data-database. when the partitions changed only the partition table in the zero-directory (and all the data that was using space Ubuntu needed for the installation) was over-written. Any data that hasn't been wiped or over-written can be recovered using software like this.

Comment: True, but the probability of actually being able to recover anything meaningful is near enough nil, especially after a full installation and the initial panic of "where's my data?" - all the while data is being written to supposedly free blocks (syslog, swap, dmesg logs) - even if a few fragments of a file are overwritten, it's still garbage. I've personally used file-recovery tools before, but never after an OS install.

Comment: Well, I've had someone come to me (as a last resort) after a OS install where I was able to regain quite a bit of useful data. It did help that the disk was de-fragmented before the installation and that the installed OS in question was small. Since Ubuntu is rather small to install as well I think that the data was fragmented and partially over-written. Incomplete data will not be recovered by testdisk. If our enquirer had a bit more technical knowledge he might be able to retrieve some useful data from "corrupted" data (think about partial photo's or video's where the video or audio skips)

Comment: i know i should keep backup of my files, i did wrong but installing new OS means not erasing all my data in virtual partitions like dis time happend with me. OS is suppose to erase primary partition not all my virtual partitions or hard disk.

Comment: This is why I explicitly added the "... fully understand what you are doing ..." sentence - if you understood what you were doing, you would have realised that installing Ubuntu would erase your data. IIRC, the Ubuntu installer even says this in nice, big letters when you select a partition option that will erase your data. If you don't read or understand these notices, you **will** erase your data without realising.